# How do I change route (IP) of tor service from the command line?

Tags: networking, ip, proxy, tor, proxychains

I'm using the `tor` package coming with the debian-testing distribution:

```
Package: tor
Version: 0.3.5.8-1
```

I'm frequently using it in combination with `proxychains` like:

```
proxychains -q curl -s -L https://ipecho.net/plain
```

how do I change the route, in order to get a new IP from the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward, as `root` use:

```
service tor restart
```

or

```
service tor reload
```